# smooth edge in WebGL Programming

Tags: javascript, webgl

When you create a sphere(Actually, It is also `apolyhedron`) or other polyhedron in WebGL native API, you will get a polyhedron with flat style, and you assign a texture to the polyhedron, It will look ugly with angle between two small face at the polyhedron suface. actually,you can subdivide the surface to get a smooth surface. and is there any other method to `smooth the surface` of the polyhedron.just look lile as the two picture as below.(the two picture is capture from the blender software)

[image: polyhedron with flat style]

[image: polyhedron with smooth style]

Here is my code for generating the sphere

```
 function getSphere(r,segment_lat,segment_lon){
      var normalData = [];
      var vertexData = [];
      var textureCoord = [];
      var vertexIndex = [],
      for (var latNum = 0; latNum <= segment_lat; latNum++) {
            var theta = latNum * Math.PI / segment_lat;
            var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
            var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
        for (var lonNum = 0; lonNum <= segment_lon; lonNum++) {
              var phi = lonNum * 2 * Math.PI / segment_lon;
              var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
              var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
              var x = cosPhi * sinTheta;
              var y = cosTheta;
              var z = sinPhi * sinTheta;
              var u = 1 - (lonNum / segment_lon);
              var v = 1 - (latNum / segment_lat);
              textureCoord.push(u);
              textureCoord.push(v);
              vertexData.push(r * x);
              vertexData.push(r * y);
              vertexData.push(r * z);
          }
      }
      for (var latNum=0; latNum < segment_lat;latNum++) {
          for (var lonNum=0; lonNum < segment_lon; lonNum++) {
            var first = (latNum * (segment_lon + 1)) + lonNum;
            var second = first + segment_lon + 1;
            vertexIndex .push(first);
            vertexIndex .push(second);
            vertexIndex .push(first + 1);
            vertexIndex .push(second);
            vertexIndex .push(second + 1);
            vertexIndex .push(first + 1);
        }
      }
        return {'vertexData':vertexData,'vertexIndex':vertexIndex,'textureCoord':textureCoord,'normalDatas':normalData};
    },
```

Fragment Shader：

```
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main(void) {
            vec3 light = vec3(1,1,1);
            vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb*light,textureColor.a);
            // gl_FragColor = vec4 (1,0,0,.8);
        }
```

Vertex Shader：

```
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        // uniform mediump mat4 proj_inv;
        uniform mediump mat4 modelViewMatrix;
        uniform mediump mat4 projectMatrix;
        varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

        void main(void) {
            //projectMatrix multi modelViewMatrix must be in vertex shader,or it will be wrong;
            gl_Position = projectMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        }
```

Comment: Use [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading).

Comment: WebGL does not have a API to create a sphere. A lib might. Thus, whether or not that sphere is smooth or flat depends on the lib's implementation.

Comment: You will not get a flat sphere. WebGL doesn't have spheres. [WebGL is just a rasterization library](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html). Spheres as shown in your picture require you to supply code or use a library.

It's actually arguably more work to get flat shaded spheres in WebGL than non flat shaded.

What have you tried?

Comment: I using native code to generate a sphere and got it,but it is a sphere with flat style, now  I want to change the sphere with flat to smooth one and how can I do at the next step

Comment: how did you get a flat sphere? Post your code

Comment: That code will is unlikely to generate a flat sphere. You're not generating any normals. Please add your shaders to the question

Comment: I have already add my shader code in the question,and how could I get a smooth sphere, thanks a lots.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I have to guess your rendered result is different than the picture you showed. What you see is a "flat" sphere in one uniform color and you want a shaded sphere, is that correct?

If so, you need to go read tutorials on how lighting works. Basically, the angle between the viewing vector and the fragment's normal is used to determined the brightness of each fragment. A fragment on the sphere that you are staring at directly have a very small angle between the view vector and its normal and thus its bright. A fragment on the barely visible edge on the sphere have a large angle between normal and view and thus it appears dark.

In your sphere generation code, you need to calculate the normals as well and pass that information to the gpu along with the rest. Fortunately for a sphere, normal is easy to calculate: `normal = normalize(position - center)`; or just `normalize(position)` if center is assumed to be at (0,0,0).

Comment: Oh,thanyou,use the method I have got a smooth sphere ,ThankYou

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. Its the (clamped) **cosine** of the angle between the surface normal and the **light** vector for [lambertian aka diffuse lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) which is **not** view dependent: `float diffuse = max(dot(normal,lightdir),0.)`. For specular lighting using [blinn-phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) one uses the *half vector* approximated by normalized *light + view*:
`float specular = pow(max(dot(n,normalize(lightdir+view)),0.) specularExponent);` Check the link for full implementations.

Comment: Shrug you are technically correct. But the method I outlined gives the desired shading effect. The main point being angle between normal and some vector is used to modulate the color of each fragment. I directed the OP to lighting tutorials if he wish to implement more sophisticated lighting models.